# dnf broken: all mirrors were tried

Tags: installation, fedora, tor, dnf

I don't know how to describe my problem because I don't understand why it happen ... When i enter

```
sudo dnf install (any packet)
```

It return me this

```
Tor Project Repo               407  B/s | 264  B     00:00    
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'Tor': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

Its obvious that Tor is related to that mess but i don't know why.

I tried nothing because I'm afraid to do something wrong. I'm on fedora 30.
(english baguette)

Comment: What happens with `sudo dnf install some-package --disablerepo='tor*'`?

Answer (score 14):

It seems like you have a broken repository. Probably you will find this repository in:

```
ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

there will probably be a file named `tor*.repo`. If you remove that file (or edit it to contain `enabled=0`), then dnf should start working correctly again.

Answer (score 8):

I tried this command and my problem fixed:

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/dnf
```

Answer (score 2):

> Failed to download metadata for repo ‘bintray–resin-io-redhat’: Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml

I was getting same error for kubernetes.repo. It got resolved by setting `enabled=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo`. Now I can download other package (example Nginx that I was unable to download).

Answer (score 0):

Execute below commands.

```
mv /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo /tmp/
mv /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates-modular.repo /tmp/
yum clean all
yum update
```

Comment: It would be valuable to add some more details on what the code is doing

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the BaseOS broken repository.

Try to edit the following files:
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-AppStream.repo

Change enabled=1 to enabled=0
If enabled=1 is not present just add enabled=0

Then try
#yum update -y